# How can I use refresh token with retrofit 2 to get new access token

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, retrofit2

I am developing android app using kotlin and I want to know if there is a best practice to fetch new token after the current token expires. I did some research but could not find any standard way of doing it. If anyone can suggest me a way about using refresh token with retrofit 2 would be nice.